# FX Implied Volatility for Longer Term Maturities

Tags: implied-volatility

To my knowledge, FX implied volatility can only be obtained from the market for time horizons up to about 5 years due to liquidity limitations.

So how would we obtain volatility estimates for longer time horizons? Is it up to the trader to decide? Or are we free to pick an extrapolation method?

Thanks,